# Sqlite min,max return wrong result in ado.net

Tags: c#, sqlite, aggregate-functions, max, min

i am using `ADO.NET Data Provider for SQLite: 1.0.82.0`

Aggregate function returns wrong result:

```
###Table structure###
CREATE TABLE ta85 (id INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, date INTEGER, _90 REAL, _100 REAL)

###Rows: ###
select * from ta85

id, date, _90, _100

"1","1355480577920","4,4","2"

"2","1355480877929","15","5,2"

"3","1355481177937","26,4","9,4"

------------------
```

Now if i want to select the max, min values for each column:

```
SELECT date,MIN(_90), MAX(_90),MIN(_100), MAX(_100) FROM ta85 WHERE date between 1355480296794 and 1355481366266
```

returns:

```
"1355481177937","15","4,4","2","9,4"
```

which for column `_100` is correct but for column `_90` is wrong.

### Solution

Thanks for all your answers. you were both right.

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(columname,"");
```

to

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(columname,0.0d);
```

Comment: Good formatting is your friend.

Comment: thank you for formatting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears you are comparing strings instead of numbers. Perhaps format your number as '4.4' instead of the '4,4'

Comment: the column is defined as real and i use a cmd Parameter to insert the value. the actual value is a double so sqlite should format the value as real?

Comment: I saw that, but the query result point out a sort on string is done.

Comment: thank you. you were both right .. changed the line "cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(columname,"");" to cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(columname, 0.0d);

Answer (score 1):

You're using the wrong kind of literal to insert floating point numbers into the database, and you're getting string comparisons. Use dots instead of commas.

Remember that SQLite is very [loose with types](http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html):

> SQLite uses a more general dynamic type system. In SQLite, the datatype of a value is associated with the value itself, not with its container.

SQL Fiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!7/f00e9/3).